# returning values from within functions

Tags: php, function

I have defined a function to check user credentials and would like it to return true if the auth passed and false if it failed. my function is defined as follows:

```
function _userLogin($username, $password){
    include 'mysqli.php';
    $logged_in;
    $mysqli->select_db('Directories');
    // query the login table for the username
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM LOGININFO WHERE USERNAME='$username'");
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    // check to see if the user exists
    if ($num_rows > 0) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM LOGININFO WHERE USERNAME='$username'";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
            while ($result_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $dbuser = $result_ar['USERNAME'];
                $dbpass = $result_ar['PASSHASH'];
                $salt = $result_ar['SALT'];
            }

        } else {
            echo "Could not connect to table: <br />".mysqli_error()."<br />";


            // create the hash for password validation
            $hash = hash('sha256', $salt.$password);

            // validate the password
            if ($hash == $dbpass){
                $logged_in = True;
                // retrieve info from the userinfo table
                $query = ("SELECT * FROM USERINFO WHERE USERNAME='$username'");
                if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
                    while ($result_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $name = $result_ar['name'];

                    }
                }
            } else {
                $logged_in = False;
                //$message = "Invalid USERNAME or PASSWORD";
                //echo $message;
            }
        }   
    } else {
        $logged_in = False;
        //$message = "Invalid USERNAME or PASSWORD";
        //echo $message;
    }
    return $logged_in;
}
```

the problem I am running into is this, when I call the function and try to use what should be the returned value I get an error that the variable is not defined.

```
_userLogin($username, $password);
    if ($logged_in == True){
    'do something';
    } else {
    'do something else'
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're discarding the returned value by not assigning it: `$logged_in = _userLogin($username, $password);` or simply `if (_userLogin($username, $password)){ ... }` - [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

Comment: now that I have done that it is always returning true, also I get an error that $logged_in has not been defined from within the function. any ideas?

Comment: Payton it has been a while and you did not select any answer, nor gave any feedback. It takes a lot to understand your problem, find a solution and write it up for you. If a solution worked for you, select and upvote it. If not, at least let us know why so we (who tried to help) can also learn from this issue

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the variable `$logged_in` that is defined in function `_userLogin` outside the block. Assign the return value that is returned by the function like,

```
$logged_in = _userLogin($username, $password)
if ($logged_in == True){
    'do something';
    } else {
    'do something else'
}
```

Also you will always receive `TRUE` because you are accessing variables `$salt`, `$password` outside the if block where they are being retrieved thus the fields not being assigned properly.

```
function _userLogin($username, $password){
    include 'mysqli.php';
    $logged_in = false;
    $mysqli->select_db('Directories');
    // query the login table for the username
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM LOGININFO WHERE USERNAME='$username'");
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    // check to see if the user exists
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM LOGININFO WHERE USERNAME='$username'";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
            $dbpass = '';
            $salt = '';

            while ($result_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $dbuser = $result_ar['USERNAME'];
                $dbpass = $result_ar['PASSHASH'];
                $salt = $result_ar['SALT'];
            }

            // create the hash for password validation
            $hash = hash('sha256', $salt.$password);

            // validate the password
            if ($hash == $dbpass){
                $logged_in = True;
                // retrieve info from the userinfo table
                $query = ("SELECT * FROM USERINFO WHERE USERNAME='$username'");
                if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
                    while ($result_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $name = $result_ar['name'];

                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            echo "Could not connect to table: <br />".mysqli_error()."<br />";
        }
    }

    return $logged_in;
}
```

PLEASE NOTE: I did not perform any logic checks other than fix your syntax

Answer (score 0):

Replace your branching (where you use the function) with the simpler:

```
if( _userLogin($username, $password) ){
  //success
}else{
  //failure
}
```